# Why is the placeholder attribute of an input tag not inheriting any CSS property?

Tags: html, css, forms, inheritance

I was trying to change the font-size of a placeholder of an input field using CSS.

Font-size of the form tag was set to 17px. It seems that the label tag is inheriting properties from the form tag. But that's not the case with the placeholders used with the input tags.

```css
form {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    font: 500 17px/3 Gotham Pro,Proxima Nova,arial,serif;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="fname">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser's default stylesheet has different values for `font-size` for those elements and you haven't overridden it.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has different styles for different elements.

For changing the `font-size` of the input and placeholder, you need to do this:

```css
input {
font-size: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if your css file is correctly linked to the HTML file:

Now choose a class name for your inputs:
<input **class="input-text"** type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">

and then in CSS:
.input-text {
font-size: 2rem; //use your own font size
}